# Dashing Meter shortenedNumber To Go Mo

Tags: dashing

Problem dashing Meter with shortened Number.

In dashing.coffee i put the "To"

```
Batman.Filters.shortenedNumber = (num) ->
  return num if isNaN(num)

  if num >= 1000000000000
    (num / 1000000000000).toFixed(1) + 'To'
  else if num >= 1000000000
    (num / 1000000000).toFixed(1) + 'Go'
  else if num >= 1000000
    (num / 1000000).toFixed(1) + 'Mo'
  else if num >= 1000
    (num / 1000).toFixed(1) + 'Ko'
  else
    num
```

Its work but not for all Meter. I have 6 Meter with same method send. I have Meter with 2.5To value send : 2466384969728 and for 1890993569792 the meter dont change the value (1890993569792 = 1.9To don't work) Have you a solution

[image]